# How to use delegates/ generics in this case?

Tags: c#

I have 2 enums enum1, enum2.

I have two functions :

```
bool func1(int param1 , enum1 type)
bool func1(int param1 , enum2 type)
```

Both functions have exactly similar structure. Only difference in all conditions is: func1 has enum1.str1 is used in all comparisons and func2 has enum2.str2 is used in all comparisons

Since both functions are similar, I want to combine the two.. What is the best way to do it?

```
func1(int param1, enum1 type)
{

      if (type.Equals(enum1.abc))
      {
        // do something
      }
      else if(type.Equals(enum1.def))
      {
    // do something
      }

}


func2(int param1, enum2 type)
{

      if (type.Equals(enum2.abcd))
      {
        // do something
      }
      else if(type.Equals(enum2.defg))
      {
    // do something
      }

}
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand. Do `enum1` and `enum2` have the exact same members? If so, why are they two different enumerations?

Comment: To clarify, both enums have the same member names i.e. `Enum1.Abc` and a corresponding `Enum2.Abc`? If so, do corresponding enum member names for each enum have the same underlying `int` value?

Comment: Could there be more than two different types? This sounds like a place for subclassing

Comment: Are you saying that the actions taken if the value is Enum1.abc would be the same for Enum2.abc?

Comment: The values of enums can be different

Comment: where is enum.str1 or enum.str2 that you say are constants throught the functions? you mean the parameter called type or when you perform the equals checking that by the way is abc and def ?

Comment: Are str1 and str2 strings?

Comment: and the return bool type is based on what out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to handle this that are simple and the decision to do this depends on the compatibility of `enum1` and `enum2`.

If they are 100% compatible, then you can imagine this:

```
bool Func1(int param1, enum1 type)
{
     switch (type) {
         case enum1.abc:
         // ...
         break
         // ...
     }
}

bool Func2(int param1, enum2 type) { Func1(param1, ToEnum1(type)) }

private static enum1 ToEnum1(enum2 type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case enum2.abc: return enum1.abc;
        // ...
        default: throw new NotImplementedException("missed a case!");
    }
}
```

Now, why am I using a function with a switch to convert instead of casting? The answer is to catch the bug when you have change the layout of one enum and not the other - that's bad.

If the types aren't compatible, consider that you could define a 3rd enum which consists of all the overlapping values plus all the non-overlapping values - you're essentially creating a proper union of the two enumerated types.  Convert to that write Func1 based on the third enum.  You can (and probably should) make the third type private to the class that's doing the work.

In essence they are essentially the same solution, it's just that in the first case one of the enumerated types is already the same as the third type.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying enum values match:

```
bool Func1(int param1, enum1 type)
{
    return Func2(param1, (enum2)type);
}
```

If they are different:

```
bool Func1(int param1, enum1 type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case enum1.abc: return Func2(param1, enum2.abc);
        case enum1.def: return Func2(param1, enum2.def);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both functions look same except the enums.. how can have just one bool Func(int param , some generic enum)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like generics is necessarily the best solution here. If you're primarily interested in reducing code reuse, you might try something like this instead:

```
func1(int param1, enum1 type)
{
    if (type.Equals(enum1.abc))
    {
        doSomethingAbc(param1);
    }
    else if(type.Equals(enum1.def))
    {
        doSomethingDef(param1);
    }
}


func2(int param1, enum2 type)
{
    if (type.Equals(enum2.abc))
    {
        doSomethingAbc(param1);
    }
    else if(type.Equals(enum2.def))
    {
        doSomethingDef(param1);
    }
}

private void doSomethingAbc(int param1) { ... }
private void doSomethingDef(int param1) { ... }
```